# Find the distribution of $X$ given that $P(X=k)=\frac 23 (k+1)P(X=k+1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A discrete random variable $X$ of values in $\mathbb N$ verifies the property that 
$$P(X=k)=\cfrac 23 (k+1)P(X=k+1)$$
What is the distribution of $X$?

I found that
$$P(X\ge 0)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cfrac 23 (k+1)P(X=k+1)=\cfrac 23\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X=k)=\cfrac 23\text E(X)=1$$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \text E(X) = 1.5$

I also found that $$P(X=k)=\cfrac{3^k}{2^k\cdot k!}\cdot P(X=0)$$
That is the only thing I could get out of the given property, I couldn't find the expression for $P(X=k)$ which is the actual question.

Comment: Be careful with the first term in the series. If $X$ assumes values in $\mathbb{N}$, the first term is $P(X=1)$, not $P(X=0)$.

Comment: Depends on what definition one has of $\N$

Comment: @user1551 and why is that? is $0\notin \mathbb N$?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka it depends on how you define it. some author will include it, some others won't

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I get it but my Prof uses $\mathbb N^*$ to denote $1,2,3,\cdots$

Comment: @F'OlaYinka I was just trying to illustrate user1551's point. I personnaly prefer to use $\mathbb{N}=0,1,2,\ldots $ as well

Comment: If you want to start at $n=1$, that will not change things very much. About worries about not seeing something "simple like that" you identified the probability part of the calculation correctly. If you didn't know a simple expression for the sum, you could call it $C$ and say that $\Pr(X=k)=\frac{1}{C}$ times stuff you can write down. That would get you most of the marks for the question.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien it's one of those notations that may never be clarified. I like using $\mathbb N_{>0} = 1,2,3, \cdots$ instead of $\mathbb N^*$

Comment: @F'Ola Yinka: During my undergraduate days, textbooks tended to denote $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ by $\mathbb{N}_0$. Without the "nought", $\mathbb{N}$ starts from 1. Maybe it's different today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good! Note that 
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots.$$
Our probabilities must add up to $1$. When we add up, we get $e^{3/2}\Pr(X=0)$. Now we can compute $\Pr(X=0)$, and therefore everything.

Comment: you mean $Pr(X=0)$ no?

Comment: Yes, changed. ${}{}{}$

Comment: My exam is in two days and i can't see something as obvious as this, I pity myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Sum these probabilities to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)=1
$$
You can then solve for $P(X=0)$